# Rails Associations Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

How do I structure these 3 models with associations?

**Issue**

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up the model associations for a personal project I'm working on. Essentially I'm building a referee assigning system consisting of 3 models:

1. Assignor: the user who assigns referees to games
2. Referee: the user assigned to the game
3. Game: has 1-4 referees assigned

What I have so far in my models is:

```
class Assignor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games
  has_many :referees
  has_many :assigned_referees, through:referees
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assignor
  has_many :referees
end

class Referee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignors
  has_many :games, through: :assignor
  has_many :assigned_games, :through:assignor
end
```

What I'd like to do with these associations within my app is:

1. List the referees an assignor has => Assignor.referees
2. List the assignors a referee has => Referee.assignors

**Where I'm having trouble is...**

3. List the referees assigned to a game
4. List the referees NOT assigned to a game
   -For Example:
   If a user(Assignor) was to pull up a game and assign a referee, I want to make a drop down that populates with a list of referees NOT assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just go for a 3 way join table:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referee_assignments
  has_many :referees, 
    through: :referee_assignments,
    inverse_of: :assigned_games
  has_many :assigners, 
    through: :referee_assignments

  def build_assignment(referee:, assigner:)
    referee_assignments.new(
      referee: referee.
      assigner: assigner
    )
  end
end

class RefereeAssignment
  # User who assigned the referee
  belongs_to :assigner, 
    class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :referee
end

class Referee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referee_assignments
  has_many :assigners, 
    through: :referee_assignments
  has_many :assigned_games,
    through: :referee_assignments,
    source: :game,
    inverse_of: :referees

  def build_assignment(game:, assigner:)
    referee_assignments.new(
      game: game,
      assigner: assigner
    )
  end
end
```

> List the referees assigned to a game

```
game = Game.find(1)
game.referees.each do |r|
  # ...
end
```

> List the referees not assigned to a game

```
referees = Referee.where.not(
  id: game.referees
)
```

Using a subquery is the simplest possible way but you could also use `NOT EXIST` or a join.

Comment: I never thought of it that way, thanks for the help. Noob question: I would need to generate the join table for RefereeAssignment? and the assignor model is fine the way I have it?

Comment: Yeah you would need to run `rails g model RefereeAssignment assigner:references game:references referee:references` and change this line `t.references :assigner, null: false, foreign_key: true` to `t.references :assigner, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }`. The Assignor model is not needed and can be scrapped.

Comment: I am assuming here that you have a class like `User` which represents the users in your application.

Comment: I figured I'd need to run that migration and I'm using Devise for User authentication so that's why I have two "User" models (Assignor and Referee) so to speak so that a User can log into their respective accounts and do what they need to do once logged in. Not sure if that changes anything...

Comment: Well you would change `foreign_key: { to_table: :assignors }` and ` belongs_to :assigner, 
    class_name: 'Assignor'`. The grammer here is pretty strange. Otherwise its really the same. This is slightly different from your solution through as a game can have many assignors.

Comment: I see what you're saying, thanks for the help/input! I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232545/discussion-between-wayoh22-and-max).